# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 20,Token in error = - ] C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlcommand, sdf

I am using a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database file (`.sdf`) in C#; with the code I can read from `albums_tbl` but I want to  read from `users-tbl` or other tables it errors :

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token
>   line offset = 20,Token in error = - ]

`albums_tbl` table has two columns: `id, name`

this is my code :

```
 private void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = C:\com_honar\test1.sdf ");

            cn.Open();

            SqlCeDataReader rdr = null;
            SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM users-tbl ", cn);
            rdr = cm.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                label1.Text = rdr.GetString(1);

            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM [users-tbl]", cn);
```

Comment: _"Try this"_ - explain this. Explain what you changed and why that is required.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are escaping the names with [] (T-SQL) or "" (ANSI SQL). You are using non-standard naming for the table with "-" .

```
"SELECT * FROM [users-tbl]"
```